# Reducing an Array

Tags: javascript

```
var x=Math.random();
x=x*600;
var k=0;
var total;
var arr=[];
if(k<10){
    k++;
    arr.push(x);
}  
if(k%2==0){
    var tot=arr.reduce(function(a,b){
        total=a+b;
        document.getElementById("a").innerHTML=total;
    }
}
```

In the above code, arr stores random values of x(upto 10 values).
    I want to display the sum of the elements after two elements are stored.
    for example, 
    if arr=[10,1] 
    then i want the total to be 11 and when next two elements(35 and 32) add to        the array
    arr=[11,35,32]
    i want the total to be updated to 78.
    total is being displayed for the first time that is when arr has 2 elements
 but total is being displayed as NaN when the next two elements to the arr(35 and 32).
    Please Help Me!!

Comment: Sri Harsha, don't forget to mark the answer of your choice as 'Accepted' in order to close the question. :)

Comment: @Joel, ok Joel. As iam new to stack,i didnt know this.

Comment: No problem, mate - welcome to SO! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.reduce()` works as a callback iterator, such as this:

```
var x = [1, 2, 3];
var sumX = x.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }); // 6
```

It loops through the array, taking element pairs and shrinking them into a single element.

With `reduce`, your array must have at least two elements to operate correctly. You can control this in several ways (the samples asume an `arr` array exists):

- Forcing the array to have at least 2 elements:

  ```
  var sum = arr.concat([0, 0]).reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });
  ```
- Validating if `b` is a number:

  ```
  var sum = arr.reduce(function(a, b) { return isNaN(b) ? a : (a + b); });
  ```

  In this case, there's no need to validate for `a` because if `isNaN(b) === true` it would mean that the array contains a single element.
- Checking the length of the array to be >= 2:

  ```
  var sum = arr.length >= 2
                        ? arr.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }) 
                        : (arr[0] || 0);
  ```

In your case, a randomized and reduced array of 10 elements would look like this:

```
var n = 10;
var arr = [];
var sum = 0;
while (arr.length < n) {
  arr.push(parseInt(Math.random() * 100));
}
sum = arr.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });
alert(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate without using reduce. Example with button:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

        var k=0;
        var total;
        var arr=[];

        function go()
        {
            var x=Math.random();
            x=x*600;

            if(k<10){
                k++;
                arr.push(x);
            }

            if(k%2==0)
            {
                var total = 0;

                for( i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ )
                {
                    total += arr[i];
                }

                document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = total;
                arr = [total];
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='a'></div>
    <input type='button' onclick='go();' value='go' />
</body>
```

Comment: Why `arr = [total];`? An array reduction returns a number, not an array of a single numeric element.

Comment: Firstly because the description said the array goes from arr=[10,1] add 35, 32 to the array and then you have: arr=[11,35,32]. I simply made the array perform how it was described to. This method does not required it though. Secondly while the post used reduce they were wanting a sum output [output should be updated to 78 (11+32+35)], thus why I removed reduce as it does seem to fit what they actually want to achieve. (At least not the simplest method)